# Spring Security: how do I get @WithMockUser to return a type object User.class

Tags: java, spring, rest, unit-testing, spring-security

When testing the controller, I had a problem. This is what the signature of the method being tested looks like in the controller:

```
public ResponseEntity<TaskCardDto> createTaskCard(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, @RequestBody TaskCardDto taskCardDto)
```

Over the tested method, I put the `@WithMockUser` annotation. When testing this method, I try to make a mock of a service that gets data from the repository:

```
TaskCard stub = ...;
when(taskCardService.saveTaskCard(any(TaskCard.class), any(User.class))).thenReturn(stub);
```

(If anything, it is not an error that I pass `TaskCard` to the service, and not `TaskCardDto`. In the controller I convert DTO to entity). But the test eventually crashes with the following error:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
taskCardServiceImpl bean.saveTaskCard(
    <any com.sin.orb.domain.TaskCard>,
    <any com.sin.orb.domain.User>
);
-> at com.sin.orb.controller.TaskCardControllerTest.createTaskCard(TaskCardControllerTest.java:67)
Actual invocations have different arguments:
taskCardServiceImpl bean.saveTaskCard(
    TaskCard(id=null, name=test, creationDate=2020-05-28, tasks=[]),
    null
);
```

As you can see for yourself, it expects to see `User.class`, but gets `null`. Is there any way for `@WithMockUser` to return an object of the User class?